# How to reuse view on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

Am having three `UIViews`(320*568). I want to reuse them on `scrollView`. Like we do with UItable cells.
AM Having `UIscrollView` of width 320X10. i.e, it can show 10 views. But I want to use only 3 views. Here's my code, But It Doesnt work well when I scroll too fast. PLease Help.

I added the same code in the - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender
It works Properly then. But It Prints NSLog("hello"); about 10-15 times, when I scroll just one page.
.
.
.
.
.

```
(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    NSlog("hello");
    int pageCurrently = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;

if (scrollView.contentOffset.x < 320)
{
    a=0;
    b=320;
    c=640;
}
else if (scrollView.contentOffset.x >= 320)
{

    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x == 320)
    {
        a=0;
        b=320;
        c=640;
    }
    else if(toCheckScrollNumber == pageCurrently )
    {

    }
    else if(pageCurrently > intPreviousPage)
    {


        largeVal=MAX(c, MAX(a, b));
        smallVal=MIN(c, MIN(a, b));

       if(smallVal==a)
       {
           a = largeVal + 320;
                      }
       else if(smallVal==b)
       {

           b = largeVal + 320;

       }
       else if (smallVal==c)
       {
           c = largeVal + 320;

       }

    }

    else if(pageCurrently < intPreviousPage)
    {

        largeVal=MAX(c, MAX(a, b));
        smallVal=MIN(c, MIN(a, b));

        if(largeVal==a)
        {
            a = smallVal - 320;

        }
        else if(largeVal==b)
        {
            b = smallVal - 320;

        }
        else if (largeVal==c)
        {
            c = smallVal - 320;

        }


    }


}

NSLog(@"a=%d , b=%d , c=%d ",a,b,c);

[_otlSubView1 setFrame:CGRectMake(a, 0, 320, 568)];
[_otlSubView2 setFrame:CGRectMake(b, 0, 320, 568)];
[_otlSubView3 setFrame:CGRectMake(c, 0, 320, 568)];

    intPreviousPage=pageCurrently;


}
```

Comment: You need to do paging  https://github.com/caesarcat/InfinitePagingView

Comment: Why don't you use a UICollectionView instead? You would get this feature out of the box.

Comment: @KakoSquid 
Well I cannot use the UIcollectionView, because of the some UI Requirements.

Comment: @amar That will BE too lengthy, I am already done with the remaining part of IU

Comment: http://www.accella.net/objective-c-using-a-uiscrollview-for-infinite-page-loops/

Comment: @amar Thanks a ton. Yeah It works. I have updated the question, Please , have a look over it

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `scrollViewDidScroll` function to do your view reuse, not `didEndDecelerating` - the latter is only called when the scroll view already slows down.

As your views are quite small (10 pixels high), it might also be that you have to add some views more in advance (eg not only one view that is to become visible, but maybe already 3 in advance - the `UITableView` also does preload a few lines more.

Comment: I have Implemented the same. Yes It, Works. But There's Some Problem, in implementing this.  There are 8 Images on the View. Which Will Come Form WEB SERVICES. I believe It Will Create Problem than. Because I NSLog("hello") in the **scrollViewDidScroll()** and print more than one time, almost 15-20 times.

Comment: scrollViewDidScroll is called a lot - every time the scroll view did scroll, as the name implies :-). Of course you should not rearrange the subviews every time the scroll view did scroll, but apply some logic to add it when needed and then leave it. Images from web services should be loaded only once and asynchronously in the background and cached (see eg this class for how to do it: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).

Comment: Yeah for the web services, now am using

(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{ }  

Where I will write the code for Web Services, and will write the reuse UIView code in  - (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *) delegate,

Soleved :)